# How to use Scrum in .NET Framework

Tags: .net, scrum

I want to know how to use Scrum in .NET Framework and why to do this?

I've studied both Scrum and the .NET Framework, but I want to know how to implement Scrum in .NET Framework.

Comment: would be really nice to do some research in wikipedia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrum doesn't distinguish by technology. The key issue is learning how to do a lot of the agile development practices in a ".NET context." For example

- Learn to use Visual Studio to write [unit tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx#bkmk_create_a_unit_test_project)
- [Refactoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/719exd8s.aspx) your code with Visual Studio (thanks to @KentMuntheCaspersen for reminding me of this critical point.)
- [Integrate](http://www.infoq.com/articles/MSBuild-1) MSBuild with [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) for continuous integration
- Add documentation with `///`

This of course pertains to the day-to-day developer activities aspect of Scrum. Of course, tools you use to organize your Product Backlog or track Sprint Burndown (like a simple whiteboard with yellow stickies) are the same no matter what you are developing with.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: A 4th key issue could be getting used to re-factor your code with Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out this oversight. I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: I thought your answer was really great, so I upvoted it. I had a small additional point with a coupling to your answer, so instead of posting a new answer I just left it in the comment to your answer. I do not accuse you for overseeing things, nor do I think the point I mentioned is more critical than any of your points. I hoped to give this guy some more ideas about what Scrum is since he sounds a bit confused. I perceived your response as some kind of hostility against me, hence I just want to let you know that my only intent was to be helpful, not taking credits for you excellent answer.

Comment: Oh no. That wasn't sarcasm at all haha. I can't believe I forgot refactoring, and I'm glad you spoke up so we could give the OP a complete answer. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the insight!

Comment: Glad to hear, I am sorry for the accusation :)

Comment: why we use scrum in .net framework?

Answer (score 2):

[Scrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28software_development%29) has nothing to do with specific software frameworks.  It is a development strategy and workflow which would work while developing any software.  You wouldn't use Scrum "in .NET", but could easily follow Scrum principles while developing software targetting the .NET Framework, or any other technology, as it's completely technology neutral.

Answer (score 0):

Scrum doesn't constrain you to specific software frameworks. However, Team Foundation Server does support Scrum development by default if you want something that is integrated with Visual Studio.